# Fixing broken csv files using awk

Tags: csv, awk

I have some csv files which are broken since there are junk such as control characters, enters and delimiters in some of the fields. An example mockup data without control characters:

```
id;col 1;col 2;col 3
1;data 11;good 21;data 31
2;data 12;cut
in two;data 32
3;data 13;good 23;data 33
4;data 14;has;extra delimiter;data 34
5;data 15;good 25;data 35
6;data 16;cut
and;extra delimiter;data 36
7;data 17;data 27;data 37
8;data 18;cut
in 
three;data 38
9;data 19;data 29;data 39
```

I am processing above crap with awk:

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }       # delimiters
NR==1 { nf=NF; }           # header record is fine, use the NF
NR>1 {
    if(NF<nf) {            # if NF less that header's NF
        prev=$0            # store $0
        if(getline==1) {   # read the "next" line
            succ=$0        # set the "next" line to succ
            $0=prev succ   # rebuild a current record
        }
    }
    if(NF!=nf)             # if NF is still not adequate
        $0=succ            # expect original line to be malformed
    if(NF!=nf)             # if the "next" line was malformed as well
        next               # well skip "next" line and move to next
} 1
```

Naturally above program will fail records `4` and `6` (as the actual data has several fields where the extra delimiter may lurk) and `8` (since I only read the next line if `NF` is too short. I can live with loosing `4` and `6` but `8` might be doable?

Also, three successive `if`s scream for a `for` loop but it's Friday afternoon here and my day is nearing `$` and I just can't spin my head around it anymore. Do you guys have any brain reserve left I could borrow? Any best practices I didn't think of?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key her is to keep a buffer containing the lines that are still not "complete"; once they are, print them and clear the buffer:

```
awk -F';' 'NF>=4 && !nf {print; next}   # normal lines are printed
           {                            # otherwise,
                if (nf>0) {             # continue with a "broken" line by...
                    buff=buff OFS $0      # appending to the buffer
                    nf+=NF-1              # and adding NF
                } else {                # new "broken" line, so...
                    buff=$0               # start buffer
                    nf=NF                 # set number of fields already seen
                }
            }
           nf>=4{                       # once line is complete
              print buff                # print it
              buff=""; nf=0             # and remove variables
           }' file
```

Here, `buff` is such buffer and `nf` an internal counter to keep track of how many fields have been seen so far for the current record (like you did in your attempt).

We are adding `NF-1` when appending to the buffer (that is, from the 2nd line of a broken stream) because a line with `NF==1` does not add any record but just concatenates with the last field of the previous line:

```
8;data 18;cut        # NF==3                           |
in                   # NF==1 but it just continues $3  | all together, NF==4
three;data 38        # NF==2 but $1 continues $3       |
```

With your sample input:

```
$ awk -F';' 'NF>=4 && !nf {print; next} {buff=(nf>0 ? buff OFS : "") $0; nf+=(nf>0 ? NF-1 : NF)} nf>=4{print buff; buff=""; nf=0}' a
id;col 1;col 2;col 3
1;data 11;good 21;data 31
2;data 12;cut in two;data 32
3;data 13;good 23;data 33
4;data 14;has;extra delimiter;data 34
5;data 15;good 25;data 35
6;data 16;cut and;extra delimiter;data 36
7;data 17;data 27;data 37
8;data 18;cut in  three;data 38
9;data 19;data 29;data 39
```